# How do I get a random "sample mean" without necessarily having a random sample.?

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures

What's an equivalent way of writing

```
    my_sum = sum(np.random.poisson(rate_variable, size_variable))
```

without actually creating an array? Basically I was running code where when the size variable was getting to the order of 10^6, it was slowing down, which one would predict. So how can I do something equivalent to what I wrote above without creating a 1 by 10^6 array?

Comment: numpy's strength is vectorization.  If you don't need that, switch back to the `math` package.  Use a generator to produce your sequence of Poisson values.

Comment: Sums of independent Poisson random variables are also Poisson, so you can draw a single random variable with appropriate parameters.